# Showing that $f(x_n)n \rightarrow 1$ when $f$ is not continuous

Tags: limits

Define $$x_n = \inf \{ x \ | \ f(x) \le \frac{1}{n}\}$$

where $f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{x}$ and $g(x)$ is a function which is **not** continuous. It may be relevant to note that $g(x)$ is a slowly-growing function (of the same order as $\log x$), so for large $x$, $f(x)$ practically behaves like $1/x$. But I don't know how to formalize that.

If $g(x)$ was continuous (for example equal to $\log x$), then it is easy to see that $f(x_n)n = 1$.

But in the case where $g$ is unknown and possibly not continuous, how do we decude that $$f(x_n)n \rightarrow 1$$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$?

It "should" still be true using intuition, but the fact that $g$ is not continuous means I can't really argue that $x_n$ will exactly make $f(x_n)$ equal $1/n$ with strict equality ...

EDIT:

Further info.

1. $f$ is always decreasing (but not necessarily strictly).
2. The domain of $x$ is imagined to be "large $x$", i.e. some interval $[x_0, \infty)$ on which $f$ is decreasing.

Comment: I think you'll need to give some further assumptions about $f$ (or $g$).  What is the domain?  And can we assume, e.g., $f(x)$ is decreasing? If not, you might have, e.g., $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} f(x) = 0$, and then $\inf\{x | f(x) \leq 1/n\} = -\infty$.

Comment: I added the info to the post.